# Split xml into smaller pieces

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery-sql

I have an xml variable.

```
DECLARE @xml xml = N'<Items Category="AAA">
  <Item Id="1">A</Item>
  <Item Id="2">B</Item>
  <Item Id="3">C</Item>
  <Item Id="4">D</Item>
  <Item Id="5">E</Item>
  <Item Id="6">F</Item>
  <Item Id="7">G</Item>
  <Item Id="8">H</Item>
  <Item Id="9">I</Item>
</Items>'
```

Could you help me write a query to split it into several pieces?

```
   <Items Category="AAA">
    <Item Id="1">A</Item>
    <Item Id="2">B</Item>
    <Item Id="3">C</Item>
   </Items>

   <Items Category="AAA">
      <Item Id="4">D</Item>
      <Item Id="5">E</Item>
      <Item Id="6">F</Item>
   </Items>

   <Items Category="AAA">
      <Item Id="7">G</Item>
      <Item Id="8">H</Item>
      <Item Id="9">I</Item>
   </Items>
```

I mean XQuery, but any other idea is welcome.

Comment: What criteria of splitting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way to do this via XQuery `modify`:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = N'<Items Category="AAA">
  <Item Id="1">A</Item>
  <Item Id="2">B</Item>
  <Item Id="3">C</Item>
  <Item Id="4">D</Item>
  <Item Id="5">E</Item>
  <Item Id="6">F</Item>
  <Item Id="7">G</Item>
  <Item Id="8">H</Item>
  <Item Id="9">I</Item>
</Items>';
DECLARE @temp TABLE (XmlData1 xml, XmlData2 xml, XmlData3 xml);
INSERT @temp VALUES (@xml, @xml, @xml);

UPDATE t
    SET XmlData1.modify('delete /Items/Item[not(position() >= 1 and position() < 4)]'),
        XmlData2.modify('delete /Items/Item[not(position() >= 4 and position() < 7)]'),
        XmlData3.modify('delete /Items/Item[not(position() >= 7 and position() < 10)]')
    FROM @temp t;

SELECT * FROM @temp;
```

Way to do this via FLWOR:

```
select @xml.query('
    <Items Category="AAA">
    {
        for $item in /Items/Item[position() >= 1 and position() < 4]
        return $item
    }
    </Items>');
```

You can freely change your split criteria in XPath.

Comment: Thank you, Ruslan, good solution.
I will take it into account.
By the way, my real xml has 130000 rows and size 350 Mb.
I'm afraid, deleting may be not the best way.

Comment: Ok, I added another solution. Check it, please

Comment: Thank you, Ruslan. It seems the most appropriate solution. 
I will implement it.